# Hanami routes helper don't work in templates

Tags: hanami, hanami-router

I have hanami application version 1.0.0
I have next routes.rb file:

```
get '/games', to: 'games#index'
root to: 'home#index'
```

I read [docs](http://hanamirb.org/guides/helpers/routing/) and tried to use

```
<%= routes.games_path %>
```

in application.html.erb template, but recieved next error:

> Hanami::Routing::InvalidRouteException: No route (path) could be generated for :games - please check given arguments

How can I use routers in hanami templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `resources`, you can also add a name to your route:

```
get '/games', to: 'games#index', as: :games
```

Read more at: https://guides.hanamirb.org/routing/overview/

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
resources :games, only: [:index]
```

to my routes.rb file and this fixed my problem.